# Vue custom import css (sass) file

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

In Vue I have a component something to below:

```js
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  .custom {
    @import "http://example.com/assets/css/style.css";
  }
</style>
```

I have an `options.json` file that can be used to set a custom CSS URL. So I can set the CSS URL to anything. How do I implement that?

**Dreamcode**

```js
<style lang="scss">
  .custom {
    @import this.options.css;
  }
</style>
```

I know my way around variables in Vue. The tricky part for me is that the are used inside `<template>` or `<script>`, not inside `<style>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
import var1 + var2 + var3 + "style.css";
</script>
```

As far as I know, you can't use cross variables (script > style) in Vue.

If you need to have a style sheet from URL, I suggest using environment variables which might work.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I don't want to use env for this, because I want it to work dynamically even after the build.

What I will probably end up doing is to always call something on the server like `style.php` and in that file load the option from the file and return the css needed. That way I can get around it, by using the condition on the server side instead.

Comment: You can always do a laodCSS funtion, but that might be a bit overkill: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/src/loadCSS.js